# How to merge conflicted files to my repository

Tags: git, github

I have a master repository that is used by two users, now when I push my code it warns me to resolve conflicts.

I want to merge my code into the existing code with git commands but I don't know how to fix this problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resolve merge conflicts in Git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/161813/how-to-resolve-merge-conflicts-in-git)

Answer (score 1):

```
$ git commit -am <message>       # add & commit your local changes
$ git pull origin master         # pull the latest codes
$ git status                     # see the files that have conflicted (untracked files)

# If you want to keep your changes then
$ git checkout . --ours

# Or, if you want to keep remote changes
$ git checkout . --theirs

$ git commit -am <message>           # add & commit with a new message
$ git push origin master             # push to remote
```

Comment: when i command git pull origin master it return error: pulling is not possible because you have unmerged files

Comment: You should add & commit your changes first. `git commit -am <message>`